# WSUS downloading unwanted updates from MS which are not selected in Options

Tags: wsus

In **WSUS** (**3.2.7600.226**), I've specified which updates we wish to download onto the WSUS server from Microsoft.

We don't use Microsoft Exchange, so it is not selected in Options > Products & Classifications.

However, this week I noticed more than 1000 new (unapproved) updates appear in All Updates, including updates specific to Microsoft Exchange, Lync, Windows Vista, etc. all of which are not selected as updates we want to download (in Options > Products & Classifications).

I've run Options > Server Cleanup Wizard, yet these updates remain, waiting to be approved.

The WSUS data directory has also increased in size by about 15 GB recently also.

Why has this happened?  How do I resolve it, and prevent it from happening again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that your WSUS database is some way damaged. For managing WSUS there is [wsusutil.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720466%28WS.10%29.aspx) program. Backup system state with all WSUS files before doing anything, also backup WSUS database with `wsusutil.exe export`. Completely remove WSUS. Install the last WSUS version, configure as you wish. Restore saved WSUS files to some location, make `wsusutil movecontent`. Then make `wsusutil reset`. This probably will prevent WSUS from downloading all updates again. If everything is OK, run Cleanup Wizard to remove unnecessary update files. If this hack doesn't work, you have a backup